# WiFi lock is not working when device goes to sleep mode

Tags: android

I am facing one strange problem, when i run my android application on the device so either it will be running on foreground or background , it should not loose the WiFi connection, for that I have get the WiFiManager and acquired the lock in Service's onCreate() method and release it on onDestroy method. But facing problem to keep WiFi turned on when device goes to sleep mode, so is there any way to make WiFi turned on even if device goes to sleep mode.
I can't acquire the lock to wake up the device because scenario is our application will run always so whenever user will not use, device should go to sleep mode but wifi connection should always be turned on.

Please do help me resolve this issue, please share some sample code also.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Services. Just insert you wifi connection code in a service, and this will run forever in background.

Comment: I am using Wifi code inside service but still when device goes to sleep mode , Wifi connection get lost.So could you please share some sample code to how to use Wifi connection inside service.

Comment: yes you have to go into seettings, under wifi, then press menu button. now an advanced menu pops up, set your wifi sleep policy to NEVER. the default is set to sleep, so you want to change this.

Comment: Okay, so what i understand is we can't override WiFi settings programmatically, we need to change the settings on the device in order to execute these scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help..

```
private void setNeverSleepPolicy() {
    try {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            int set = android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, set);
        } else {
            int set = android.provider.Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, android.provider.Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, set);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work on devices of normal users as only system apps can set these settings; exception will be thrown otherwise.